# How can I fetch only the latest nested column within view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

If I'm trying to fetch this only within view.
How can I?

**controller**

```
@last_comment = @topic.comments.last
```

**view**

```
<%= @last_comment.user.nickname %>
```

Should it be something like this?

```
<%= topic.comments.last.user.nickname %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
topic.comments.order("id").last.user.nickname
```